# Near given coordinates, print hello in Swift, MapKit and corelocation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, core-location

I would like to know how to check if person is near some coordinates and then do something like say hello into console for testing. Right now I have already got user location and it is going to update every time person moves but how to know if he is near some coordinates or address? For example:

```
func sayHello(){
if mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude == 26{
print("Hello")
}
```

Code I've done already:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is every time you update the user's location, check the distance between your user's location and the address location(s) you have stored. If the user is within x meters, print "Hello".

Below is code I would use to get the distance between your user and the address. If you have an array of objects that contain your addresses and their coordinates you could loop through each address and print Hello for each address that is within x meters.

```
let userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 10.000, longitude: 29.000)
let addressLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 15.000, longitude: 20.000)
let meters:CLLocationDistance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(addressLocation)
```

Comment: If I understand U right then the "userLocation" is my given coordinates and "addressLocation" is how far person can be from those coordinates? So lets suppose that my coordinates are 58.369015901(latitude) and 26.717840259(longitude). If I am 15.000 (latitudes) and 20.000 (longitudes) away from my given coordinates, it would print out "Hello"? How much I can round those coordinates?

Comment: Lets say you have User A and Restaurant B. You want to print Hello if User A is within 100 meters of Restaurant B. userLocation is the coordinates of User A. addressLocation is the coordinates of Restaurant B. You then use distanceFromLocation to get the distance in meters between userLocation and addressLocation. You store this in the meters constant. You don't need to round the coordinates. Just store them as a Double.

Comment: Wow, I almost got you. It is so much brain work this late. So If I say:
if meters == 5 it means User A can be 5 meters away from Resturant B and it still prints out "Hello"?

Comment: I would do something along the lines of... if meters <= 5 { print("hello") } This will print hello if your user is within 5 meters of the restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

Get the distance between two coordinates and match if its less than 5m than show print statement

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```